# ffmpeg croping 1080p video and encode to 720p at once

Tags: ffmpeg, crop, 1080p

Im tring to remove black boarders (crop) in a video I have in 1080p and encode it to 720p at the same time using ffmpeg, but Im having problems finding the right filters and commands for it.

Any one albe to help?

Comment: Do you know how much to crop?

Comment: yes, I have the crop command/filter, I just need to know how to put it all togetter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain the filters together.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf crop=w:h:x:y,scale=-2:720 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to crop top/bottom. So think right command would be; ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf crop=w:h:x:y,scale=1280:-2 -c:a copy out.mp4                         If Im not wrong..

Comment: Your Q title says 720p. Either way, you won't get 1280x720, so it's upto you to decide the target dimensions.